# Maya .IFF plugins for Gimp

Tags: windows, 3d-meshes, gimp, maya

Maya's preferred format for saving off a UV Snapshot is its own .IFF format, so I was hoping to find a plugin allowing Gimp 2 (Windows) to read it. I've found plenty of plugins for different linux distros, but none are win-friendly (that I can discern - admittedly I'm no whiz with Gimp). Does anyone know of one?

Alternately, .tiff seems to work just fine, so if there's no good reason to bother fiddling with IFFs, I'd appreciate the input there, too.

(sorry if this isn't on-topic)

Comment: did you try on http://superuser.com/ ? It would definitely be IT there.

Comment: SU's not really in scope for 3D design, sadly. Figured I'd try here, until we can eventually get http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-techniques-and-software off the ground. I noticed a few 3D questions got some traction here and thought I'd give it a go. ;)

Answer (score 1):

TIFFs work well, but the most widely used file format in 3D graphics is TGA. If you have existing .iff files that you need to work with then that's a problem, but for rendering out your own images use TGA.